# Finding numbers with distinct digits in a range using loops

Tags: java

Desired behaviour: print and count all numbers between 1 (inclusive) and `lim` (exclusive) that have distinct digits, that is, not the same digit twice.

Specific problem: The program runs in an infinite loop.

This is what I have already done. but it is not working. I tried printing the values at each step but it keeps on giving 1 in infinte loop.

What did I do wrong?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    double limit=sc.nextDouble(); // reading the range of numbers from 0 to limit-digit number
    int count=0,total=0;
    int lim=(int)(Math.pow(10.0,limit)); //setting range from 0 to 10^limit
    System.out.println(lim);
    for(int i=1;i<lim;i++) {
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(); //making a hash set to include the unique elements
        System.out.println(i);
        while (i > 0) {                           
            int tempVal = i % 10; //each digit is extracted and stored in       hash set if unique
            set.add(tempVal);         
            i = i / 10;
            count++;
            //System.out.println(count);
        }
        count+=1;
        if(count==set.size())
       {
            total++;
        }
        count=0;
    }
    System.out.println(total);
}
```

Comment: use a debugger and you will find it out

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]

Comment: Can you add comments in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem in your loop :

```
while (i > 0) {//<<------------
```

---

To solve your problem you have inverse the order of your condition instead of :

```
while (i > 0) {
```

You have to use :

```
while (i < 0) {
```

Or it is also logic to replace the `i` in your loop :

```
while (i > 0) {
```

With `count` like this :

```
while (count > 0) {
```

Comment: shouldnt  i=i/10 give zero when it is i=1 because i is integer type?

Comment: Yes, @RohitJaiswal

Comment: @RohitJaiswal yes this is correct, another solution is to check with `while (i < 0) {` instead of `while (i > 0) {` this will solve your problem

Comment: The answer does not make sense. When you keep on dividing `i` by 10, it will become `0` at a point, and hence no longer be `> 0`.

Comment: `while (i < 0)` makes no sense either. `i` will never become `< 0`, so that loop won’t run at all.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is you are using `i` for two purposes. `i` is your loop control variable from 1 to `lim`. You modify `i` inside the loop, then it will no longer work as loop control variable. It will never reach `lim`, so your `for` loop will never terminate.

Instead you need to work in a copy of `i` when deciding whether `i` has distinct digits, so you can do your calculation without modifying `i` itself.

Comment: mm, i think this is more logic, and correct i really don't notice that in my solution Ole V.V. i think this answer should be the correct answer @Rohit Jaiswal you have to accept this answer instead of my answer (+1) you deserve it